# PHP 5.4 - ini_set('max_execution_time', 30); does not work

Tags: php, linux, apache, debian

I have installed PHP 5.4 (Debian 7) and a php script with the line

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 30);
```

because the "max_execution_time" does not change for that php script.

What's wrong?

Comment: did you check the return value? it's boolean FALSE on failure.

Comment: Some (or most) webhostings does not allow change these settings such as `max_execution_time` via PHP script. Sometimes it is fixed and you cannot change it or you can change it via their hosting administration.

Comment: No no, this is on my own root server, not on a webhosting paket.
echo ini_set('max_execution_time', 10); results 30 ?!?

Comment: Then try it by htaccess put: `php_value max_execution_time 30`

Comment: But i only will change the setting in one php script, not on every php script that runs.

Comment: If you want only in one script, then instead of this ini_set() use http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 0):

[Manual for `ini_set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php):

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns the **old value** on success, FALSE on failure.

Therefore:

```
echo ini_set('max_execution_time', 30); // prints 10 (or whatever the old value was)
echo ini_get('max_execution_time'); // prints 30
```

But as advised by Mr. Smith, prefer `set_time_limit();`.